# Is there a Qt wrapper available for libspotify?

Tags: qt, spotify

As you can guess I am at Qt developer and in the interest of getting up and running with libspotify as quickly as possible I am looking for a Qt wrapper.

I did come across this link https://github.com/romnes/libqspotify but as you can see the source is two years old. I am guessing libspotify has moved on a lot since then.

Does such a wrapper even exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[QSpot](http://qspot.garage.maemo.org/) appears still to be in development and is based on libqspotify (they have copied the libqspotify sources into their qspotify_src directory). There are some recent commits (August 2012) to that directory, so I'd guess their classes are fresher than the ones you found on GitHub.

The sources of QSpot are [found here](http://gitorious.org/qspot).

If that doesn't work for you, there is also MeeSpot which is based on a library called libQtSpotify, located in [MeeSpot's sources](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/meespot).

Comment: Excellent, though QSpot looks like it is built against version 9 of libspotify and MeeSpot version 10. Hopefully I can piece something together to support version 12 in my development.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [Tomahawk](http://www.tomahawk-player.org/index.html). It's also [open source](https://github.com/tomahawk-player/tomahawk?source=c)